# How to pass field attribute value to Django form field error message

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to change form validation error message *"This field is required"* to include field's label, e.g. *"Name field is required"*. Does Django provide a simple way to refer to field attributes in error messages?

```
errors = {
    'required': _('{label} field is required')
}

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label=_('Name'), error_messages=errors, max_length=80)
    age = forms.IntegerField(label=_('Age'), error_messages=errors)
```

I know I can override form's `__init__` method to construct error messages as I want, but I would like a cleaner way.

Comment: nope, pretty sure you have to override `__init__`

Comment: @Anentropic You are not right. Look at default **Invalid_choice** message: *Select A Valid Choice. %(Value)S Is Not One Of The Available Choices*.

Comment: That's not relevant to the case of the "field is required" error message, which doesn't take any formatting vars. However I think overriding the form's `__init__` may not be the best way either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use Python string formatting in the error messages, but you probably need to use a custom `Field` sub-class.

For the specific error message you want to customise - a required field - Django's `Field` class just raises the error without attempting any string substitutions:

```
def validate(self, value):
    if value in validators.EMPTY_VALUES and self.required:
        raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'])
```

(`ValidationError` does not do any either)

Some other errors allow some specific vars in the error string (to find them just search for `raise ValidationError` in `django/forms/fields.py`) but one problem Django has in giving you what you want is the field instance *doesn't know its own name*. Unless you passed in a `label` kwarg the field instance doesn't know its label either, so at the point where the exception is raised Django has nothing to give you.

In your case, you *are* passing in custom labels for all fields, so you could try the following mixin to ease making the custom field classes you need:

```
class RequiredErrorMsgMixin(object):
    def validate(self, value):
        if value in validators.EMPTY_VALUES and self.required:
            raise ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['required'].format(label=self.label)
            )

class CustomCharField(RequiredErrorMsgMixin, CharField):
    pass

class CustomIntField(RequiredErrorMsgMixin, IntField):
    pass

errors = {
    'required': _('{label} field is required')
}

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = CustomCharField(label=_('Name'), error_messages=errors, max_length=80)
    age = CustomIntegerField(label=_('Age'), error_messages=errors)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right that instance is not accessible for the error message by default. But since I have loads of different fields, I chose to use CustomFormMixin, which simply iterates through all fields in its ``__init__`` method and updates the message: ``field.error_messages['required'] = _(error_message).format(field.label)``.